# JavaScript, Matter.js: Increase radius of circle

Tags: javascript, physics-engine, matter.js

I have a small example script, where I have a circle (radius:40), which falls down to the ground. But when I increase its radius to 80 then, only the graphics of the circle seem to change, but not the physics:

```
<html>
<body></body>
</html>
<script src="matter.js"></script>
<script>
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies
engine = Engine.create(document.body,{render:{options:{wireframes: false}}})
engine.render.options.background = "#7f7f7f"
ground = Bodies.rectangle(400,590,800,20,{isStatic:true})
World.add(engine.world, ground)
circle = Bodies.circle(400,20,40,{render:{fillStyle:"#0000ff"}})
World.add(engine.world, circle)
Engine.run(engine)
setTimeout(increaseRadius, 1500)

function increaseRadius(){
  circle.circleRadius = 80
}
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that with your approach you also have to call World.add(engine.world, circle) again and possibly remove the previous circle with the smaller radius since the engine works with a copy of the circle.
Alternatively, you might be able to call the scale method on the body: http://brm.io/matter-js-docs/classes/Body.html#method_scale

Comment: But then all the other physics are gone, at least if the circle is moving. But I see, if I can restore these things..

Comment: I assume that there is no pointer to the global circle you created when you pass it to world but that a copy of it is created. So when you change the radius of the circle, it does not affect the copy that is actually being used.

Comment: You might be able to call the scale method on the body: http://brm.io/matter-js-docs/classes/Body.html#method_scale

Comment: Thank you!, please update the post, so I can rate for the answer

Comment: By the way, before I open another thread for that, do you know a way to turn of collision for a single body? So that it simply gos through all other objects?

Comment: You should be able to assign a different groupId to bodies that you do not want to collide http://brm.io/matter-js-docs/classes/Body.html#property_groupId

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90178/discussion-between-unknown-and-benbo).

Comment: @benbo is right, you should use `Body.scale` if you need to change the size of a body after creation. Note that `body.circleRadius` is only used as a hint for smoother circle rendering. Regarding your question about disabling collisions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683832/javascript-matter-js-disable-collision-for-one-body

Comment: Another problem with removing the object during a collision loop is if the object ever collides with two objects at once you might not be able to recognise the object because it has been removed from the world and likely your own references and you might be looking for the new object.